# Rounding to the Nearest Ending Digits

Tags: php, math, numbers, rounding

I have the following function that **rounds a number to the nearest number ending with the digits of $nearest**, and I was wondering if there is **a more elegant way** of doing the same.

```
/**
 * Rounds the number to the nearest digit(s).
 *
 * @param int $number
 * @param int $nearest
 * @return int
 */

function roundNearest($number, $nearest, $type = null)
{
    $result = abs(intval($number));
    $nearest = abs(intval($nearest));

    if ($result <= $nearest)
    {
        $result = $nearest;
    }

    else
    {
        $ceil = $nearest - substr($result, strlen($result) - strlen($nearest));
        $floor = $nearest - substr($result, strlen($result) - strlen($nearest)) - pow(10, strlen($nearest));

        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'ceil':
                $result += $ceil;
            break;

            case 'floor':
                $result += $floor;
            break;

            default:
                $result += (abs($ceil) <= abs($floor)) ? $ceil : $floor;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($number < 0)
    {
        $result *= -1;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Some examples:

```
roundNearest(86, 9); // 89
roundNearest(97, 9); // 99
roundNearest(97, 9, 'floor'); // 89
```

Thanks in advance!

**PS: This question is *not* about rounding to the *nearest multiple*.**

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function roundToDigits($num, $suffix, $type = 'round') {
    $pow = pow(10, floor(log($suffix, 10) + 1));
    return $type(($num - $suffix) / $pow) * $pow + $suffix; 
};
```

`$type` should be either "ceil", "floor", or "round"

Comment: Always rounds numbers down, returns `79`, `89` and `89` for the examples provided in my question.

Comment: Did you change the `$type` parameter?
`roundToDigits(94,9,'floor')==89`, `roundToDigits(94,9,'ceil')==99`, `roundToDigits(94,9,'round')==99`

Comment: Ooops, no I didn't! :O Neat solution, I would just change `$pow = pow(10, floor(log($suffix, 10) + 1));` to also handle decimals. Thanks!

Comment: It just came to me, how would you handle `$suffix = 0`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, and it's more elegant to me, at least:

```
function roundNearest($number, $nearest, $type = null)
{
  if($number < 0)
    return -roundNearest(-$number, $nearest, $type);

  $nearest = abs($nearest);
  if($number < $nearest)
    return $nearest;

  $len = strlen($nearest);
  $pow = pow(10, $len);
  $diff = $pow - $nearest;

  if($type == 'ciel')
    $adj = 0.5;
  else if($type == 'floor')
    $adj = -0.5;
  else
    $adj = 0;

  return round(($number + $diff)/$pow + $adj)*$pow - $diff;
}
```

**Edit**: Added what I *think* you want from negative inputs.

Comment: There's too much repetition for it to be elegant.

Comment: @Reinis I.: OK I made it a little eleganter.