# Rounding float up to first non-zero value

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, floating-point

guys, I have some very little floats and I want to round it up to first not nil value.
For example:

```
float toRound = 0.000002125231553;
toRound = //Operations//;

toRound == 0.000002;
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Your example rounds *down* though ?

Comment: It should round like round function (if next number < 5 - down, else - up)

Comment: You probably need to give a couple more examples in your question as it's not really clear exactly what you are trying to achieve here - do you just want one significant digit or are you looking for a specific number of decimal places ?

Comment: I want to round float to integer, but it shouldn't be nil. If rounded to integer value equals nil, we should look for numbers after dot.

Comment: What you mean is rounding to one significant digit.
It's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751055/rounding-with-significant-digits

Comment: possible duplicate of [rounding with significant digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751055/rounding-with-significant-digits)

Comment: The first non-zero _integer_ value, rounding _up_ from a fraction, 0 < n < 1, is 1. Problem solved. Obviously this isn't the solution you're looking for; please try to explain more clearly. The best way to do that is to give some a variety input and output samples.

Comment: For future readers, if you're rounding w/ floor function you can just use `%g` in your NSString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps not the best approach. but it does what you want ;)

```
float s = 0.000322333123;
BOOL exit = 0;
NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", s];
for (int i = 0; i <= [x length]; i++) {
NSString *t = [x substringToIndex:i];

if ([t floatValue] == 0 || exit == 1) {
    ;;
}
else {
    exit = 1;
    s = [t floatValue];       
}
}

NSLog(@"round: %f", s);
```

Log: round: 0.0003

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I was thinking about six hours, but didn't found solution.