# Objective C calculator displaying scientific notation

Tags: objective-c, formatting, calculator

So I've coded a calculator in objective C and I've formatted the display in .4g as I wanted only significant digits and 4 decimal places. This works fine :)
What I would like it to do is not display 2.34E+05 etc when it displays a longer number like 234,000. I've allowed it to autosize the text in the label so I know it isn't just that the label is too small. 
Is there a piece of code that will make it display the actual number instead of the scientific notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting with `%f` instead of `%g` won't use [standard form](http://www.gcse.com/maths/standard_form.htm).

Have a look at this [specification](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

---

Edit 1:

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751827/916299) to help with the rounding.

```
-(float) round:(float)num toSignificantFigures:(int)n {
    if(num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double d = ceil(log10(num < 0 ? -num: num));
    int power = n - (int) d;

    double magnitude = pow(10, power);
    long shifted = round(num*magnitude);
    return shifted/magnitude;
}
```

I then combined these two options to get:

```
NSLog(@"%.0f", [self round:number toSignificantFigures:4]);
```

---

Edit 2:

What about this:

```
- (NSString *) floatToString:(float) val {
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f", val];
    unichar c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];
    while (c == 48 || c == 46) { // 0 or .
        ret = [ret substringToIndex:[ret length] - 1];
        c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks as if it limits decimals to 5, then removes any trailing zeros or decimal points.

<sub>[[Source]](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37665-float-to-string-removing-trailing-zeros.html)</sub>

Comment: but then %f displays number like 234.00000 and i don't want the non significant digits?

Comment: You can still use the `%.4f` to limit decimals.

Comment: I would try just changing that `g` to an `f`

Comment: That limits decimals but still displays insignificant 0 after the decimal place....

Comment: Yeah, noticed that was stupid of me to ask i thought you could use 2 parameters, but those 2 wouldnt work in conjunction anyway. >.< but yeah f doesn't remove insignificant digits so i get 234.00000. Limiting decimals isnt the issue it's removing non significant digits

Comment: Sort of, but i don't want to limit the amount of sig figs, i want to limit the amount of non sig figs to 0 lol. I could just leave it using the e+05 thing as it seems to be such a pain but it just doesn't look right to me >.<

Comment: I'm sure that'd do it if it does what you say it does, i have no idea how to put that into my program atm though, only been learning for a week >.<